# Criteria with collections

Tags: hibernate

I am having a rough time dealing with Hibernate criteria and collections.

I have the following relations:

- A has many elements of B
- A has one element of C
- C has many elements of D
- D has one element of E

So basically

**E**<----1----**D**<----*----**C**<----1----**A**-----*---->**B**

I am trying to fetch all elements of A whose C elements verify certain conditions on C's attributes, plus have at least one element D that is related to a specific E.

So this is my Criteria so far:

```
session.createCriteria(A.class)
                .createCriteria("Cs")
                .add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("attributeA", 1), Restrictions.eq("attributeB", 2)))
                .createCriteria("Ds")
                .createCriteria("E")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("id", 123);
```

This works okay, but the sql I am getting from Hibernate as a result does a select with all attributes of C, D and E, which I don't need (only need to filter by them). How can I restrict these and use only those relations for filtering?

Also, I do want elements B to be fetched, otherwise I am getting a collection which I have to initialize individually, which results in a lot more queries. How can I build a criteria that includes those?

Comment: Known bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3538

Comment: So there are no workarounds for this? The bug is from 2011! Also, can you help me with my second question?

Comment: The workaround would be to use HQL.

Comment: For your second question, use `setFetchMode("B", FetchMode.JOIN)`

Comment: I tried that but didn't work; I got no B elements...